# store terabytes of data and later import to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-s3, redis, relational-database, google-cloud-storage

I am looking for a good way to store up to 20 terabytes of data (social media postings, twitter data, etc) in the cloud and gradually feed it into Elasticsearch (to enable faceted searching) so that it can be quickly searched. I was going to break this into 2 steps. Saving the data to storage and then indexing it (the next day or the next month). I have seen mention of Redis. Would this be appropriate? Would it be better to use AWS and S3 or Google to do this? Is there a better way to do this then using Redis? Once the data is indexed I don't need the original data anymore.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. The datastore is only a small part of the problem. There is reading the datastore, the transforms to JSON, the bulk loading, the index/shard routing and balancing to consider.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to store 1 terabyte of data in Redis with the intent of later importing it into Elasticsearch?

Comment: You can take a look at Google Cloud Storage for storing your data. You can choose from different types of storage: Standard Storage, Durable Reduced Availability (DRA) Storage, and Nearline Storage. Each type of storage has different availability, latency, throughput characteristics and pricing. All storage classes offer the same high level of durability. For more info you can visit [this link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes). You can spin up Elasticserach cluster in few click on GCP with [Cloud Launcher](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher).

Answer (score 1):

AWS is a natural fit, the S3 uploads are free. They have a hosted ElasticSearch and Redis/ElasticCache, or you could host your own on EC2.  Redis is an in-memory key value store not well suited for dynamic search, whereas ElasticSearch is a persisted document store perfectly suited for search and aggregation.

If you enable S3 Events, then a file create event could trigger an AWS Lamba written in Python or other language, to automatically read your data whenever a file appears and insert using ElasticSearch http API.  The first 1 million Lamba executions per month are free.  The ElasticSearch index properties let you choose which fields that will automatically be indexed for search.

After you finish with the AWS data then delete it or change its storage type to Infrequent access or reduced redundancy to save on your bill.  I use http://www.insight4storage.com/ to lower my S3 costs by tracking my storage usage trends.

Comment: Thanks for a great roadmap. To clarify, the AWS Lamba will used to write the incoming data to Elasticsearch. If I have 3 million per day that would cost 60 cents/day or $18/month and each of these 3 million could write multiple fields to Elasticsearch right?

Comment: Yes, the lamba could read the file referenced by the event, and insert the data in elasticsearch using its HTTP API.